# How do I copy a file and append a number inside?

Tags: linux, bash, file-transfer

This one has baffled me – I'm actually trying to make a Thunar custom action to copy the selected file into the same directory appending a number before the extension, e.g.

```
cp file.ext file_1.ext
```

Some commands seem to do this automatically like the `mogrify -format` (except obviously the extension changes).

For example I'd like to copy an image file so that I can `mogrify -resize` the copy (which will be overwritten).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to do this in bash is with [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). If the `file` variable holds the filename do something like this:

```
name=${file%.*}
extension=${file##*.}
i=1
new_file="${name}_${i}.${extension}

cp "$file" "$new_file"
```

To use this in a script (`duplicate.sh` say), do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=${1%.*}
extension=${1##*.}
infix="${2:-_1}"

cp -v "$1" "${name}${infix}.${extension}"
```

Then call it as:

```
duplicate.sh FILE INFIX
```

Comment: You could of course wrap that in a shell function and actually copy the file.

Comment: Forgot it was about copying, modified answer.

Comment: `cp "$name"{,_1}."${extension}` can be used to eliminate the need for the `new_file` variable.

Comment: @chepner Post that as an answer.

Comment: for safety, one could include a loop checking whether new_file already exists, to avoid it being overwritten (something like `while [ -f "$new_file" ]; do i=i+1; new_file="${name}_${i}.${extension}; done`).

Comment: can't get thor's script working and chepner, that's what i needed i think but can't get it to work in thunar custom action, izzy: that line would go before the cp line right?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I used your script, with the #!/bin/bash at top, named it duplicate.sh and put it in /home/myusername and chmod +x . then the custom action will be `/home/usname/duplicate.sh %f` , nothing happens.  I also found out `cp %n %n_1` copies the file and appends to the end and the file still executes, so that's a solution too.

Comment: I added a script example to the answer, let me know how you get on. `cp $n $n_1` works, but this is a _suffix_ not an _infix_.

Comment: thanks for helping thor, I tried this script and the file duplicates indeed, but with only `_` infixed and no number.  trying to duplicate it a second time and nothing happens at all. And after this, how could it be used for multiple files -because I'm in Thunar here not the bash terminal.

Comment: what's up with the two dollar infix? :)

Comment: In Bourne shell scripting `$1, $2, ...` represent positional parameters given to the script, so in the case of `duplicate.sh` above `$1` holds the filename and `$2` is what is to be infixed.

Comment: well `${infix}` still passes nothing to the new file name

Comment: Did you give `duplicate.sh` two arguments?

Comment: two arguments being what exactly?

Comment: As in `duplicate.sh file_you_want_to_copy the_infix`

Comment: OK, I'm with you now, that worked.  I hadn't specified the infix at all.  but can the script make it automatic?  using a line like @izzy posted here.

Comment: Replace `infix="$2"` with `infix="${2:-_1}"`. This sets `infix` to `_1` it isn't defined. I updated the example.

Comment: that works fine.  just how can it work for multiple files selected?

Comment: `for file in *; do duplicate.sh $file; done` will apply put the `_1` infix in all files in current dir.

Comment: to make this perfect, I'd like to add a loop as Izzy suggested, to check if file with infix exists already, and increase the infix value if necessary so as not to over-write a file. So how can that be added to the script Thor has made?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slightly shorter version of @Thor's answer:

```
name=${file%.*}
extension=${file##*.}

cp "$name"{,_1}."$extension"
```